# When executing a command via xp_cmdshell what user issues the command to the system?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, remote, xp-cmdshell

I'm executing the following command to stop a service on a remote server from within a stored procedure in SQL Server.

```
----------------
-- Stop Service
----------------
SET @Command = 'sc \\' + @Server + ' stop ' + @ServiceName;
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command;
```

Depending on the service sometimes this executes successfully but other times I receive the following error:

```
[SC] OpenService FAILED 5:
NULL
Access is denied.
NULL
NULL
```

Im curious what user executes the command.  Is it the user I login/connect with to the database?  Or is it the user Im logged onto the physical server with?  Can I pass in different authentication with the `xp_cmdshell`?

Comment: You can see who it's running as via `EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell 'whoami';`

Comment: Also, does sometimes mean sometimes on the same server, or does sometimes really mean on some servers?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - in all scenarios the service is running on a different server, and both instances the remote service was run as 'Local System'.  However on one of the servers, the user ID that was running SQL Server was also an admin on the remote server.  So I believe _tpet was correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [xp_cmdshell (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) in the product documentation:

> The Windows process spawned by **xp_cmdshell** has the same security rights as the SQL Server service account.
>
> When it is called by a user that is not a member of the **sysadmin** fixed server role, **xp_cmdshell** connects to Windows by using the account name and password stored in the credential named **##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##**. If this proxy credential does not exist, xp_cmdshell will fail.

See the full entry for the steps you need to take to set up the `xp_cmdshell` proxy account.